# Product Sum of Special Arrays

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, arrays

[image: (depth)*]

**Can someone please explain why this is correct:**

```
function productSum(array,depth=1) {
    let sum=0;      
    for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(Array.isArray(array[i])){                                            
            sum+= productSum(array[i],depth+1)
        }else{
            sum+= array[i];
        }
    }       
    return (depth)*sum;
}
```

**But, following is wrong:**

```
function productSum(array,depth=1) {
    let sum=0;      
    for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(Array.isArray(array[i])){                                            
            sum+=(depth)* productSum(array[i],depth+1)
        }else{
            sum+= array[i];
        }
    }       
    return sum;
}
```

I haven't been able wrap my head around it. Why is does it give wrong answer if I multiply the sum with depth before the for loop on an array ends?

It is clear from the sample output that if there are multiple array items at a depth, we are supposed to multiply the sum with the depth as many times.
Eg. depth 2 is multiplied by the sum twice in the example.

Could someone please break it down for me?

Comment: You need to multiply by depth in both branches of your if in the second example.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Please credit the original source of all copied material.  Please don't use images for text or mathematics; instead, please [edit] the question to transcribe them and credit the source.  Make sure your question is self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

here, you are multiplying the depth of the "parent" array, instead of the nested array.

```
sum+=(depth)* productSum(array[i],depth+1)
```

try this

```
 sum+=(depth+1)* productSum(array[i],depth+1)
```

multiply it by depth+1

Comment: Does this give the *Sample Output* for the *Sample Input*?